# Getting auto completion work with rustlings in VSCodium?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, autocomplete, rust-analyzer, rust-rustlings

I am running VSCodium version 1.85.2, rustc and rust-analyzer 1.76.0, and the rust-analyzer Visual Studio Code extension version 0.3.1839.

The extension is partially working. I get syntax errors, for example, from this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let answer = current_favorite_color();
    println!("My current favorite color is {}", answer);
}

this doesn't belong here

fn current_favorite_color() -> String {
    String::from("blue")
}
```

It correctly produces 14 "problems", including:

```
Syntax Error: expected BANG rust-analyzer (syntax-error)
Syntax Error: expected `{`, `[`, `(` rust-analyzer (syntax-error)
Syntax Error: expected SEMICOLON rust-analyzer (syntax-error)
```

However, when I'm trying to type actual rust code, pressing `^-spacebar` only gets me the "abc" suggestions. So, for example, I would expect typing `answer.` followed by `^-spacebar` in the above code (assuming I remove the invalid code first) to get me a list that includes the `trim` function.

What do I need to do to get that working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rustlings` cli tool has a command to make rust-analyzer work on the exercise folder.

```bash
rustlings lsp
```

It will create a `rust-project.json` file

This was mentioned in their [README](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings?tab=readme-ov-file#enabling-rust-analyzer).

Comment: I didn't know that half an hour ago, that's going to make these exercise more pleasant for sure!

Comment: I know, right?! It's so much easier.